# What is difference between Activity getIntent and TaskStackBuilder getIntent()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

As I read from google blog [post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/tasks-and-the-back-stack-dbb7c3b0f6d4#.g6dck3mde) that every activity which we start using startActivity() added to back stack, so what if I try to getIntent() from TaskStackBuilder instead of Activity getIntent() , can i get the same activity intent ?

I am trying to understand the task and back-stack , please help whether I have understood it correctly ?

Comment: Do you really need to use TaskStackBuilder? Because it is deprecated. But, basically, we use it when we want the user to navigate to another activity after pressing back button.

Comment: "we use it when we want the user to navigate to another activity after pressing back button" : It means it has all the activity intents stored (in a list as i have seen TaskStackBuilder source code) so can't we get the intent of particular activity using index or somehow ?

Comment: Using 'TaskStackBuilder' can be pretty tricky. It makes a lot of assumptions and tries to "do the right thing", which more often than not is the wrong thing and your app doesn't behave the way you want. I've answered many questions about this by basically telling people not to use it because it does a lot of stuff under the covers that isn't well documented. To help you, please explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Utility class for constructing synthetic back stacks for cross-task navigation on Android 3.0 and newer.

In API level 11 (Android 3.0/Honeycomb) the recommended conventions for app navigation using the back key changed. The back key's behavior is local to the current task and does not capture navigation across different tasks. Navigating across tasks and easily reaching the previous task is accomplished through the "recents" UI, accessible through the software-provided Recents key on the navigation or system bar. On devices with the older hardware button configuration the recents UI can be accessed with a long press on the Home key.

When crossing from one task stack to another post-Android 3.0, the application should synthesize a back stack/history for the new task so that the user may navigate out of the new task and back to the Launcher by repeated presses of the back key. Back key presses should not navigate across task stacks.

TaskStackBuilder provides a backward-compatible way to obey the correct conventions around cross-task navigation on the device's version of the platform. On devices running Android 3.0 or newer, calls to the startActivities() method or sending the PendingIntent generated by getPendingIntent(int, int) will construct the synthetic back stack as prescribed. On devices running older versions of the platform, these same calls will invoke the topmost activity in the supplied stack, ignoring the rest of the synthetic stack and allowing the back key to navigate back to the previous task.

Activity getIntent()
Return the intent that started this activity.

Comment: Copy and paste from the documentation isn't really the best way to answer a question.